# Setting up Cloudflare CNAME to work with Microsoft Exchange

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, cloudflare

We have a hosted website that uses Cloudflare to improve website speed performance and load times. As such, the DNS details for the site currently include:

- -MX records leading to the hosting provider for emails.
- -CNAME record for the hostname to be routed via Cloudflare for website performance

We recently decided that we wished to move our email mailboxes from the hosting provider to Microsoft Exchange. However, Microsoft has advised that as part of the migration process, we need to create a CNAME record in CloudFlare to allow for autoconfiguration of Microsoft Outlook to pickup mailbox settings associated with the hostname. However, CloudFlare only allows for 1 CNAME to exist which is currently used to route website traffic via CloudFlare.

Question: I don't want to get rid of CloudFlare services by changing the CNAME record to point to Microsoft's outlook configuration address for Exchange. Is there anyway that I can create an additional CNAME record? I came across *CNAME flattening* but i'm not sure if it would be applicable in this scenario or what the steps would be to implement it. This surely can't be the first time someone has wanted to have their website traffic routed via Cloudflare but their hostname also to be used for Microsoft Exchange email.

I'm hoping there is some creating way around it, even if it's creating a subdomain (e.g. traffic.domain.com) which one CNAME can route web traffic to CloudFlare to while another subdomain (mail.domain.com) has a CNAME to route to Microsoft's outlook autoconfig.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please open a [support ticket](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us) and we can assist. If we are managing your DNS fully, there is no limitation to the number of CNAMES in settings. You should still be able to put a CNAME in your DNS settings pointing to Microsoft.

Comment: Hi - I did open a ticket (Request #191027) and was told that it's not possible to add another CNAME. Can you look into the ticket and reply as it's causing us huge problems with not being able to move to Exchange without leaving CloudFlare

Comment: I'm going to update the ticket & try to work it from there. I know other customers have a similar setup & it shouldn't be an issue if we're managing the DNS for the domain.